# Taking data from a data.txt file in JSON format and displaying it randomly on the GUI

Tags: python, json, random

I have to import the data.txt file currently having 3 dictionaries (can have more as well) and to randomly select the name of an item and print it on the GUI. The code above is designed to do the required but it doesn't do anything. Can you please help me with this.

```
with open('data.txt') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        data_file.close()
self.firstPrompt = tkinter.Label(self.top, width=7, \
                       text=random.sample(data['name'], 1), fg='blue', font=("Helvetica", 16))
```

Immediate help will be appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you're missing, you've got more code, which somewhere you should also have `self.pack()`, and `mainloop()`. Adding those to your code works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MCVE:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Label, mainloop, Tk
import json
import random

class myGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Tk()
        with open('data.txt') as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                data_file.close()
        self.firstPrompt = Tkinter.Label(self.top, width=7, \
                       text=random.sample(data['name'], 1), fg='blue', font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.firstPrompt.pack()

myGUI()
mainloop()
```

using `data.txt`:

```
{  
   "name":{  
      "name_0":"",
      "name_1":""
   }
}
```

Should pop-up a tkinter label window showing `name_1` in blue, Helvectica, 16, etc.